# Why don't the pros kill the scouting probe as it passes through their mineral line?

Tags: starcraft-2

While watching pros play (MLG, GSL,etc) I notice that sometimes a player will move a probe/drone/scv right through the other player's mineral line.  I have yet to see a pro try to kill this drone as it passes through.

When someone does this to me, I often have my drones all attack the scout, killing it pretty much instantly.  I am only gold, so if I can manage to do this often, I am sure a pro could.  Is there a reason they don't?  I know I lose mining time, but I feel that I gain by not having to worry about what that scout is doing, esp if it is a probe or scv that could be used to harass my early hatch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sending *all* your workers to try to kill a scout; even if it's already in your mineral line, will probably put you down more than the 50 minerals your opponent lost, as that could be 5+ seconds times 10-15 workers. At [43 minerals/worker/minute](http://sc2armory.com/forums/topic/19605), that's barely break even, plus you might be losing the opportunity cost of spending your APM elsewhere.

Answer (score 14):

So the problem you're running into is that you're trying to kill a Gold Level Scouter.  Most people as this level only queue up a few way points and go back to their base to do something else.  Often times they'll do silly things like send their Probe right through your mineral line, instead of around the back, or ignore their Probe until it takes a hit or two.

Once you get to higher levels you run into people who have higher micro skills and avoid obvious traps like those you're describing.  Even though you'll occasionally get a surround on them they know things like the mineral trick (harvesting from a Mineral patch gives harvesters unit walking) and easily avoid death.

More often than not, killing a Probe (before you have attack units) is a waste of your time unless its trying to become bothersome.

Comment: SC2 has waypoints? Good to know. I was wondering how many decades it would take for Blizzard to catch up with the 90s in terms of RTS features.

Comment: @Sparr Warcraft 3 also had way points, but I understand what you mean.

Comment: Didn't SC (1) have waypoints too?

Comment: your answer was just as good as nick's, but it looked like Nick needs the bonus rep more than you do at this point :)

Comment: @Peter I actually think his answer is wrong, but this is your decision

Comment: I thought you both were saying "it's not worth it" with slight variations on why.  when you say it is a waste of time to kill a probe, your reason seems to be that it is unlikely to work because a pro can micro out of a surround before the scout dies, whereas nick is saying it is a waste of time because you lose more minerals than you "gain" by killing a 50 mineral unit.

Comment: @Peter it is not a waste of time to kill a Probe if you can kill a Probe.  The loss of scouting information heavily outweighs the loss of minerals from mining (not to mention you can group 6-7 Drones and get an easy surround with minimal loss).  The problem becomes killing that Probe.  Against a good player it is not feasible.